# Why not use more than 48kHz with HeSuVi

Tags: surround-sound, frequency-response, stereo-to-surround, 3d

So I recently installed the HeSuVi app in preparation for the t50rp Mk3 headphones I've ordered (hoping that they'll sound good enough running directly from my Creative AE-5 sound-card and that I won't also have to shell out cash for an amp here).
After some tinkering I also managed to split and apply the surround emulation to my Roccat Kave 5.1 individual Analogue 3.5 plugs and... it sounds amazing! Testing it at 96kHz sounds cleaner than 48kHz to me (probably due to the lower noise-floor)
However, the manual for HeSuVi reccomends I set audio output to 41 or 48kHz.

Anyone with experience using this app, could you tell me if  applying the equalization (not the 3D emulation which sounds fine and works just as well if not better at 96kHz) for the t50RP mk3 should sound at 96kHz vs 48kHz.

Also, please don't start the old debate of whether I should be able to tell the difference between 48kHz and higher, as I can (and they sound thinner, probably because of the increase in dynamic range for the Trebble)